# C# - Self reference to Generic Collection

Tags: c#

Will it throw an error if we create a class like below?
Since StudentCollection referring to the same class.
And Which one is correct?

1.

```
public class StudentDetail
    {
        public Collection<StudentDetail> StudentCollection { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public Guid StudentID { get; set; }
        public int RollNo { get; set; }
        public Guid ClassID { get; set; }
    }
```

2.

```
public class StudentDetail
        {
            public Collection<studentinfo> StudentCollection { get; set; }

        }

Public class studentinfo
{
public string StudentName { get; set; }
            public Guid StudentID { get; set; }
            public int RollNo { get; set; }
            public Guid ClassID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, what happens if you try?

Comment: It should work.  The problem will be size of object.  What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari I have modified the question. Which one is correct.

Comment: Obliviously the second approach is correct as you are creating the cross reference in the first approach.

Comment: @Gaurav - Will first approach create any issue. Since I have used this approach in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that works without a problem. You can have a `Collection<ThisClass>` in a class in the same way you can also have a member of the same type in a type. For example this is also perfectly valid:

```
class Person
{
    Person Mother { get; set; }
}
```

So the question remains if it's best practice. In my opinion not, because you say that every single instance is also a collection of itself. You should have a class that holds it like this:

```
class University
{
    IEnumerable<StudentInfo> Students { get; set; }
}
```

But sometimes it might be correct if we take the first example:

```
class Person
{
    Person Mother { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Person> Children {get; set; }
}
```